# Cron Expression Notation

Tags: cron

I want to write a crontab entry to run every 30 minutes for the last week of every month. I know to do the final Sunday for instance the cron is:

```
0 0/30 * ? * 0L
```

When I try to comma separate the weekday field like so:

```
0 0/30 * ? * 0L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L
```

I get an error:

```
Support for specifying 'L' with other days of the week is not implemented
```

Is there a way to short hand this crontab expression, or do I need to make 7 separate crontab entries each with a different day?

Comment: do you need last week of month starting from Sunday or just last seven days of the month?

Comment: Which `cron`?  There's many: [vixie-cron](ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/cron/), [cronie](https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/), [dcron](http://www.jimpryor.net/linux/dcron.html), [fcron](http://fcron.free.fr), [mcron](http://www.gnu.org/s/mcron/), …

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says you can't do this. You'll have to have your script check if today is within the last week of the month and exit/proceed as required.

```
#!/bin/bash

MonthDays=$(echo $(cal) | awk '{print $NF}')
Today=$(date '+%d')
let DaysLeft=MonthDays-Today

if [ $DaysLeft  -gt  6 ]
then
    exit 1
fi
echo "Run the rest of the script"
```

Alternatively you could use the script below in your crontab - save it as `last-week`

```
#!/bin/bash

MonthDays=$(echo $(cal) | awk '{print $NF}')
Today=$(date '+%d')
let DaysLeft=MonthDays-Today

if [ $DaysLeft  -gt  6 ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

Use it like this

```
0,30 * * * * last-week && your-script
```

Which says run `your-script` if the `last-week` script exits with a 0 status.

Comment: That works for last 7 days of the month not the last week. Though it is ambiguous what to call 'last week'

Comment: @Dada: Given the OPs defective crontab spec `0L ... 6L` and their later statement `... or do I need to make 7 separate cron ...` It seemed fairly clear to me that they meant last 7 days of the month.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want real 'last week' (as from last Sunday of the month to whatever it is left), make some changes to @Iain's script:

```
#!/bin/bash

Today=$(date +%d)
LastSun=$(ncal | awk 'NR==2 { print $NF }')

if [ $Today -ge $LastSun ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

Use it in a same manner.